# Change pin state permanently using libgpiod in C

Tags: c, linux, raspberry-pi, gpio

I am writing a C program, which controls GPIO state on Raspberry PI. I am using `libgpiod` and call this function:

```
gpiod_ctxless_set_value(GPIO_CHIP_NAME, RESET_PIN, 1, false, "some consumer",  NULL, NULL);
```

But, immediately after function execution pin changes its state back to LOW. How to change it permanently? Or, at least, till program exit?

Comment: I guess this is too high level for your needs. The reason why it reverts back to the default state is the file of the device being closed. Your routine shall open the file, do things, close the file. I’m sure the context is used for that, versus *ctxless* variant you mentioned above.

Comment: Ah, I see! It looks like I need to use `gpiod_line_set_value` function and keep context

Comment: @0andriy What is the benefit of gpiod_ctxless_set_value function then? I think this is a bug.

Comment: @MehmetFide, as long as you don’t close the file you may just set or get values independently, it may be good in case when you want just to bitbang a pattern. Not a bug definitely.

Comment: @0andriy but as I understand from the OP, gpiod_ctxless_set_value() function is the one opens and closes the file automatically, no?

Comment: @MehmetFide, maybe I was unclear. I meant two cases: when you don’t close the file and when you close it after each setting. In the latter case you always need to rely on edges, rather than states, but yes, it’s a bit fragile if one does something to the line in between. https://www.i-programmer.info/programming/hardware/14457-pi-iot-in-c-using-linux-drivers-gpio-character-driver.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @0andriy mentioned, for my purposes I need more low-level functions, not a contextless. Here is my test example with generic `libgpiod` functions.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <gpiod.h>

#define LED_PIN 28

int main()
{
        struct gpiod_chip *gpiochip;
        struct gpiod_line *gpioline;
        int ret;

        gpiochip = gpiod_chip_open("/dev/gpiochip0");
        if (gpiochip == NULL)
                goto error1;
        printf("gpiochip open is ok\r\n");
        gpioline = gpiod_chip_get_line(gpiochip, TEST_PIN);
        if (gpioline == NULL)
                goto error2;
        printf("gpioline open is ok\r\n");
        ret = gpiod_line_request_output(gpioline, "gpio", 0);
        if (ret != 0)
                goto error2;
        printf("request output is ok\r\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
                ret = gpiod_line_set_value(gpioline, 1);
                printf("LED on\r\n");
                sleep(1);
                ret = gpiod_line_set_value(gpioline, 0);
                printf("LED off\r\n");
                sleep(1);
        }
        gpiod_line_release(gpioline);
error2:
        gpiod_chip_close(gpiochip);
error1:
        return 0;
}
```